# How to use KotlinPoet to get correct TypeName for PropertySpec

Tags: kotlin, kapt, kotlinpoet

Using KotlinPoet, in order to generate a PropertySpec for adding  properties to classes and constructors, you need a TypeName object.

The TypeMirror.asTypeName() KotlinPoet function is deprecated, because it won't always work correctly for Kotlin types.

But I can't find a single example of how to get a correct TypeName for a Kotlin class (e.g. kotlin.String) using the kotlinpoet-metadata APIs, the way the deprecation message says.

The docs for kotlinpoet-metadata APIs also seem completely broken (go to https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/interop-kotlinx-metadata/#interop-with-kotlinx-metadata and click anything under the APIs section)

Does anyone have an example of how to replace TypeMirror.asTypeName() with some kotlinpoet-metadata code to get a TypeName, so that I can create a PropertySpec?

Comment: Do you know the class you're referring to in advance, or is the class determined by your annotation processor and it's only available as a TypeMirror?

Comment: the class is provided in the processor as an annotated element, so I only have a type mirror.  I know in this case that the current breakage is with a String.  asTypeName always produces java.lang.String, but I need kotlin.String.

Comment: Correct links to API docs:[interop-kotlinx-metadata-classinspectors-elements](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/elements/com.squareup.kotlinpoet.classinspector.elements/index.html),[interop-kotlinx-metadata-classinspectors-reflect](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/reflect/com.squareup.kotlinpoet.classinspector.reflective/index.html),[interop-kotlinx-metadata-core](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/core/com.squareup.kotlinpoet.metadata/index.html),[interop-kotlinx-metadata-specs](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/specs/com.squareup.kotlinpoet.metadata.specs/index.html)

Comment: Also there is a missing link in Overview section: [KotlinPoet-metadata-specs](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/interop-kotlinx-metadata-specs/)

Comment: For when the class is determined by your annotation processor and it's only available as a TypeMirror, are there any available examples? Links seem to 404. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not very sure if this aligns with the intention of the deprecation message, but this is what I got it to work.

I first had to add kotlinpoet-metadata-specs.

```
implementation("com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.7.1")
implementation("com.squareup:kotlinpoet-metadata:1.7.1")
implementation("com.squareup:kotlinpoet-metadata-specs:1.7.1")
```

Then use a util method from `com.squareup.kotlinpoet.metadata.specs.internal.ClassInspectorUtil` to create className.

```
val packageName = getPackage(element).qualifiedName.toString()
val typeMetadata = element.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java)
val kmClass = typeMetadata.toImmutableKmClass()
val className = ClassInspectorUtil.createClassName(kmClass.name)
```

then use

```
val funSpec = FunSpec.builder("allNullableSet")
                     .receiver(className)
                     .returns(Boolean::class.java)
                     .addStatement(statement)
                     .build()
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful, but `ClassInspectorUtil` is marked as `internal` in kotlinpoet. I wonder if there is a way to get a `TypeName` from an `ImmutableKmClass` using the public API?

Comment: This also won't work for properties, since only classes get Metadata annotations.  In this case, for constructor parameters, I can use:

`annotatedElement.enclosingElement.getAnnotation(Metadata::class.java).toImmutableKmClass().constructors[0].parameters`

to get the ctor parameters, but they are `ImmutableKmValueParameter`s, not classes.  Any way to get a TypeName for an `ImmutableKmValueParameter`?  I can maybe pose a new question for this case...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the `TypeName` of a `TypeElement` in my `AbstractProcessor`, thanks to having access to its `processingEnv`:

```
val kmClass = (typeElement.kotlinClassMetadata() as KotlinClassMetadata.Class).toKmClass()
val elementName: TypeName = ClassName(processingEnv.elementUtils.getPackageOf(typeElement).toString(), kmClass.name.substringAfterLast("/"))
```

It should also be doable without `processingEnv` by splitting the `kmClass.name` manually.